# Table of Contents web part displays pages even when "Show Pages" is unchecked

Tags: web-part

I've added a Table of Contents web part to a site which has three sub-sites and a bunch of pages. I want this web part to display *only* the sites, not the pages.

In the ToC properties I've unchecked the "Show Pages" option, yet the web part continues to render the pages!!

How can I fix this?

I've also found that ToC will display libraries which I have deleted, which is another frustration for me.

Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a free 3rd party web part that does what I need: it displays all the subsites within a site (one level deep).

http://sharepoint247.com/sharepoint2010/sharepoint-2010-subsites-webpart/

I'm deployed it (just now) and it's working so far.